# set C standard in qmake

Tags: c, android-ndk, standards, qmake, c11

For android purpose I am forced to use qmake instead of cmake.
I can set C++ standard to C++11 using

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

but I also have some C files which uses C11 . when I compile them I get errors like

error: blahblah only allowed in C99 or C11 mode

So I tried

```
CONFIG += c11
```

which is also not working . what can I do set it to gnu11 or c11

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve it this way

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=gnu11

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you try to force qmake to `c++11`, but you still have the same errors as it is not `c++11`.  Try

```
#incude <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << __cplusplus;
}
```

Compiler that supports `С++98/03` builds a program that prints 199711
For `С++11` the output is 201103
For `С++14` it is 201300 or 201402
**You have to rebuid your project after editing .pro file**